# Set Y value in pixels in amchart

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

I have a chart with icons that are drawn as a simple line with bullets. The data is like this
[["18-07-2021",64], ["19-07-2021",64],["20-07-2021",64], .... ]
I manually set the Y value as 64 (max data value). But I want to set this line with icons in pixels offset from the top border of the chart, so it was always on the same height(now when the data changes the Y char max value changes). Is there a way to do so? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Please share a sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) so that your issue is easier to replicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the min/max to add the gap between max value and the top of the chart. For example:

```
valueAxis.min = 0;
valueAxis.max = 130;
valueAxis.strictMinMax = true;
```

See documentation from https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/valueaxis/#max_property